# ListView not appearing in fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

So I have two Fragments inside an Activity using a `PageAdapter`.

One of the Fragments is a Listview and the other is a GridView of images.

The fragments are created successfully but the ListView is empty

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventlist ,container, false);
    String[] x = new String[]{"AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC","AAA","BBB","CCC"};

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
    listView.setAdapter(test);
    return view;
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not check null for listview. But rather check if the list is empty.

Change it to listView.getChildCount()==0.

But I think you dont need to check because it will always be empty because it's a new created view. And no items on the list. If you want to check correctly, put the condition check after you set the adapter to the list.

Check if this works.

Comment: with that check, the code doesnt get run at all, how can I fix it ?

Comment: Sry. My mistake, change it to listView.getChildCount()==0. This means if your list is currently empty, add the items to the list.

Comment: no because when I set the `if` statement to `listView.getChildCount() != 0` the code never gets run and if it stays as `listView != null` it will get to line`setAdapter(test)` but still nothing happens

Comment: @cxzp it will always be zero cox you initialize listview and then check with if condition however you do not populate listview before the if condition and from what i see you do need the if condition

Comment: @Raghunandan i am not following, please see the code above I have edited it to remove the condition - yet it still doesnt work

Comment: @Joe138 i have removed any conditioning alltogether, see the edited code above but still nothing

Comment: @cxzp do you get any excpetions? also` getActiviy()` is enough  `ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
    listView.setAdapter(test)`